# In .NET 5, is there a way to ahead-of-time compile code into the binary and strip just the IL (not the reflection data)?

Tags: c#, .net

I understand that reflection data is necessary for some code to function and cannot normally be stripped, but I am not talking about reflection data (i.e. types, method signatures etc.). I want to strip just the IL code - i.e. the bodies of the methods, so that the app cannot be decompiled.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is technically possible to ahead-of-time compile IL to machine code, it's not officially supported as part of .NET 5 (or any other version of .NET).

Unity uses its [IL2CPP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html) processor to AOT compile .NET assemblies to native libraries for various platforms.  It is only supported for Unity applications and is not open source.

[IL2CPU](https://www.il2cpu.net/) is an open source project that seeks to achieve the same object, but it is unclear how close to finished it is.